# What is the execution flow in react component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What is the flow of execution in react component, I have a react component, something like this

```
const EmployeeList = () => {

    //First part of the component is fetch call to get the data from database
    //Second part of the component is JSX which renders the fetched employee data, something like below

};
```

My question is since the first part is a fetch call and its asynchronous, what will be the flow of execution, does JSX render always waits till the the upper code finishes

Comment: Could you please insert the code of the component properly?

Comment: there is an initial render first, so the jsx is rendered first, and then the useEffect in wich you probably placed your api call is triggered. Right afteryour state is probably updated, wich causes a rerender with the data you fetched

Comment: Well, the component you're *showing* isn't a valid React component at all.  Because it doesn't return anything.  Your code consists of a function which contains two comments and no actual functionality.  So the "flow of execution" of *this component* is that React will try to render it, see that it returns nothing, and produce an error.  If you have a different example, a [mcve] which is doing something you don't expect, we could perhaps help with that if you were asking about that...

Comment: @David "_Well, the component you're showing isn't a valid React component at all. Because it doesn't return anything._": [That's no longer true since React v18](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/21869)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the component is first initialized for mounting, all the code in the component will be executed asynchronously unless a code block is set to run after the mounting phase -- in useEffect's or componentDidMounts.

So if you have a JSX block in the render function that is dependent on the data being fetched in the same component, then the component will crash unless there's a check set in place for it.

To answer your question, no the JSX will not wait for the data to be fetched unless explicitly coded to do so.